# isHappy function in Java

Tags: java, recursion, numbers

I am trying to make a method isHappy that will return True if a given integer is a happy number, and false otherwise.

A number is happy if one can reach the number 1 by repeatedly taking the sum of the squares of its digits. e.g. 397 is a happy number:

397 -> 139 -> 91 -> 82 -> 100 -> 1

Numbers that are not happy will loop and thus never reach 1. e.g. 123 is not a happy number:

123 -> 14 -> 17 -> 50 -> 25 -> 29 -> 85 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 -> ...

To find out if a number is happy or not, I tried to use a recursive algorithm that requires three extra items to be maintained.  1) A number that has been seen already that will be remembered for a fixed number of steps, 2) the number of remaining steps that we will remember this number for, and 3) once we forget this number, how long we will remember the next number we see for (which will be one step longer than the last number was remembered for).

When the number we are remembering becomes the same as the next number in the sequence,
we know we have reached a loop and can then stop.

This is my code :

```
public static boolean isHappy(int n) {
     assert n > 0 : "n should be positive";
     // Post: Returns true if a number is 'happy', unless false.
     return checkHappiness (n, n/2, n/8, n/16);  
  }

private static boolean checkHappiness (int n, int r, int t, int nt) {
    // A (hidden) helper function of 'isHappy' that counts additional parameters.
    if (n == 1) return true;
     else if (n == r) return false;
      else if (t > 0) return checkHappiness (sumSquareDigits (n),r,t-1,nt);
       else if (t == 0) return checkHappiness (n+1, n, nt, nt+1);
    return true;
  }
```

I should mention that the arguments of the helper function are: the current number (n), the number currently being remembered (r), how long that number will be remembered for (t), and the amount of time the next remembered number will be remembered for (nt).

This works fine except with the case of 2. For some reason it thinks 2 is a happy number but it is not! Can anyone see where is my error? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to do it recursively? If it helps Rosettacode.org provides a non-recursive java examples of what you want: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Happy_numbers#Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, (I can't run it to check) it appears the problem is here:

```
else if (n == r) return false;
```

The number 2 repeats the following pattern:

```
2, 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16, ...
```

But, it never equals the original number 2. Therefore that if will fail

Answer (score 0):

As you have already determined, `2` is not a happy number.

2 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4 (seen already).

It's not clear why you are willingly holding on to a number only for so many iterations.  It took many iterations to prove that `2` isn't a happy number.

It would be more correct to hold on to a `List` of numbers that are already seen, and pass that `List` from recursive call to recursive call.  Then if the current number is already in the `List`, it's not happy.  Else, add to the current number to that `List` for the next call.

Comment: I know 2 is not a happy number.

What I'm saying is that when the input is 2 the output is true for some reason.. 

I know that there are much easier ways. I am doing this only by interest and for practice.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; I was double-checking for myself.  Now I've included "As you have already determined, ".

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you need with relative ease by using a `List` to hold numbers that you've seen in previous calls, so you can determine, no matter how long the chain, when to quit. You can probably employ a "counter" or something that will allow you to quit after so many calls, but this should get you what you want.

```
public class HappyNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HappyNumber hn = new HappyNumber();


        int[] tests = new int[]{397, 2, 12, 129, 139, 91, 56};

        for ( int i : tests) {
            String not = hn.isHappy(i) ? "" : "not";

            System.out.println(i + " is " + not + " happy");
        }
    }

    public boolean isHappy(int num) {
        return checkIsHappy(num, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    private boolean checkIsHappy(int num, List<Integer> numsSeen) {
        // list is null, no bueno
        // check against 0 and negative numbers (Math.abs might help with the negatives, but let's keep it simple)
        if ( numsSeen == null || num <= 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( num == 1 ) {
            return true;
        }

        // we've already seen this number, the number is not happy
        if (numsSeen.contains(num)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // compute new number
            int newNum = sumSquareDigits(num);
            // add the number to the list
            numsSeen.add(num);
            // recurse, passing the list
            return checkIsHappy(newNum, numsSeen);
        }
    }


    // helper function
    private int sumSquareDigits(int num) {
        int sum = 0;
        int digit;
        while ( num > 0 ) {
            digit = num % 10;
            sum += digit*digit;
            num /= 10;
        }

        return sum;
    }

}
```

This test produces the following output:

```
397 is happy
2 is not happy
12 is not happy
129 is happy
139 is happy
91 is happy
56 is not happy
```

I purposely stuck some numbers in there from your chain on "397" since they are implicitly happy. The rest are random selections

Answer (score -1):

From debugging your application it looks like using 2 for input will result in n = 1 somewhere along execution, it will fall into a lengthy recursion. However, eventually we will get this pattern

```
n = 86;
r = 85;
t = 6;
nt = 7;
```

Afterwards we will get

```
n = 100;
r = 85;
t = 5;
nt = 7
```

Which will result in the sum of 100 to be 1, making 2 happy. I'm not sure why this happens, but from debugging this is the result I am getting

Here is the string leading up to 100, keep in mind this is using your code, and since you didn't provide a `sumSquareDigits(int n)` function I made my own.

`2 3 4 16 17 50 25 26 40 16 37 38 73 58 89 145 146 53 34 25 29 85 86 100 1`